Translate my PDF with "puppeteer" in NodeJs
My main goal is to translate a single PDF page in the free translation service in Google Translate with puppeteer in nodejs.
Here's my code:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  // Launch a headless browser
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  // Open a new page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Replace the URL below with the URL of the PDF you want to translate
  const pdfUrl = 'https://www.cbu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/2019-20-ece-computersystems-cs.pdf';

  // Navigate to the PDF translation page
  await page.goto(`https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=${encodeURIComponent(pdfUrl)}`);

  // Wait for the translation page to load
  await page.waitForSelector('#contentframe iframe');

  // Get the source URL of the translated content iframe
  const iframeSrc = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector('#contentframe iframe').src;
  });

  console.log('Found iframe:', iframeSrc);

  // Navigate to the translated content iframe
  await page.goto(iframeSrc);

  // Wait for translation to complete
  await page.waitForTimeout(5000); // Adjust the timeout as needed based on the translation complexity

  // Print the translated content to PDF
  await page.pdf({ path: '/tmp/translated_pdf.pdf' });

  console.log('PDF translation completed successfully.');

  // Close the browser
  await browser.close();
})();

Here are the errors it gave me:
richardsonoge@richardsonoge-blooglet:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf_translator$ node translate_pdf.js
/opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf_translator/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/WaitTask.js:50       
            this.#timeoutError = new Errors_js_1.TimeoutError(`Waiting failed: ${options.timeout}ms exceeded`);                                                                                                       
                                 ^                                                   

TimeoutError: Waiting for selector `#contentframe iframe` failed: Waiting failed: 30000ms exceeded
    at new WaitTask (/opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf_translator/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/WaitTask.js:50:34)                                                                           
    at IsolatedWorld.waitForFunction (/opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf_translator/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/api/Realm.js:25:26)                                                                              
    at PQueryHandler.waitFor (/opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf_translator/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/QueryHandler.js:170:95)                                                  
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)       
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:442:9)                              
    at async CdpFrame.waitForSelector (/opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf_translator/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/api/Frame.js:468:21)                                             
    at async CdpPage.waitForSelector (/opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf_translator/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/api/Page.js:1309:20)
    at async /opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf_translator/translate_pdf.js:17:3    

Node.js v18.13.0                                
richardsonoge@richardsonoge-blooglet:/opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf_translator$

How can I fix them and make this code work?

Just pasting the URL into the browser doesn't work for me, so it won't work in Puppeteer either. You're trying to translate an English PDF to French, right? The URL you create is https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbu.edu%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2020%2F05%2F2019-20-ece-computersystems-cs.pdf which doesn't do the translation just visiting it directly. I'd start by getting that working, then only switching to Puppeteer once you have a valid human browser workflow. There are probably off-the-shelf tools that do this without having to use Puppeteer, in any case

@ggorlen I also do this in the browser but it doesn't work. Can you fix it for me by giving me another code that will work 100% out of the how please?

I'm not going to guess your use case, spend a bunch of time and make a bunch of assumptions only to find it doesn't fit your use case. Best to figure out a strategy using human browser manipulation. Then share what those steps are and try automating it in Puppeteer. Like I said, there's no point in (anyone) starting work with Puppeteer until you have a sequence of human actions that work.
